# Adblock Plus not working after update to Firefox 4.0b6 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, adblock

Firefox recently updated itself on my Ubuntu 10.04 from 4.0b5 to 4.0b6. After a browser restart, Adblock Plus 1.2.2 which was installed no longer blocks any ads. The extensions appears as if it is installed and compatible with the FF version, but the preferences button doesn't bring up the prefs and ads are contaminating my surfing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First, just restart FF and see if you can get the AdBlock preferences dialog open.  If you can, then do the following.

1. Click the "Filters" menu.
2. Select "Add filter subscription"
3. Select the subscription you want to subscribe to and hit "add subscription".

If you can't get it open, uninstall the add-on and reinstall, then subscribe to the filter list after a FF restart like you normally would.